# Tensorflow: curve fitting with logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, regression, curve-fitting

I have a dataset where each row is a (x, y) tuple. So, each row is a point of a curve in the X-Y plane. I would like to do logistic regression for it.

Following the examples give [here](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/), I have created the model in the following chunk of the code.

```
# tf Graph Input
X = tf.placeholder("float")
Y = tf.placeholder("float")

# Set model weights
W = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias")

# Construct a logistic model
pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.mul(x, W) + b) # Softmax
```

I am getting the following error in the last line.

> ValueError: Shape () must have rank 2

I have two 1D vectors one for the X values and the other for the Y values. I am not sure why I should have something with the shape of rank 2.

Comment: @Alex, it is defined as follows. rng = numpy.random

Comment: It's hard to debug without more of the stack. tf.nn.softmax takes a matrix, not a vector, so you might need to reshape its input to have rank 2.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a different variable name (`x` instead of `X`) in the calculation of the softmax.

Change

```
pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.mul(x, W) + b) # Softmax
```

to

```
pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.mul(X, W) + b) # Softmax
```